# dynamically disabling days in pikaday datepicker

Tags: jquery, css-selectors, jquery-selectors, pikaday

I'm trying to dynamically change which dates of the month are allowed in a pikaday datepicker based on changes to a username field. i.e. use something like the below to disable all but the 1st of each month. the selector is however not working. i've tried a number of variations. any ideas?

```
$("#username").on('change', function() { 
 if(.........){
   $('.pika-button :not([value="1"])').prop("disabled", true);
 }
});
```

here's the inner html of one of these, if it helps:

```
<button class="pika-button pika-day" type="button" data-pika-year="2018" data-pika-month="11" data-pika-day="1">1</button>
```

thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

```js
$(function() {

  $("#username").on('change', '.buttonWrapper', function() {
    $('.pika-button:not([data-pika-day=1])').prop('disabled', true);
  });

});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<body>
  <div class="buttonWrapper">
    <button class="pika-button pika-day" type="button" data-pika-year="2018" data-pika-month="1" data-pika-day="1">Month=1, Day=1</button>
    <button class="pika-button pika-day" type="button" data-pika-year="2018" data-pika-month="5" data-pika-day="1">Month=5, Day=5</button>
    <button class="pika-button pika-day" type="button" data-pika-year="2018" data-pika-month="2" data-pika-day="2">Month=2, Day=2</button>
    <button class="pika-button pika-day" type="button" data-pika-year="2018" data-pika-month="3" data-pika-day="4">Month=3, Day=4</button>
    <button class="pika-button pika-day" type="button" data-pika-year="2018" data-pika-month="4" data-pika-day="4">Month=4, Day=4</button>
  </div>
  <input type="text" id="username" />
</body>
```

Comment: didn't work. also, i don't really want to remove the options, since i would like them to be re-enabled if the username changes to something that doesn't fall under the condition